# Como evitar esta mensagem de erro? "main.cpp:8:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c++

Estou obtendo a mensagem de erro: "main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   ((-10))/76=n-1;"

No trecho de código abaixo,alguém sabe o motivo?

```
#include 
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int ano;
  cin>>ano;
  int passagem;
  int n;
  (ano-10)/76=n-1;
  passagem=(10+76)*(n-1);

  }'
```

Comment: Você esta tentando usar o sinal de igual que é usado para definir valores de variaveis para setar o valor em outro valor? Isto não tem muito sentido `(ano-10)/76=n-1;`, o sinal de `=` é usado para setar valores em variaveis, como por exemplo `int a = n-1;`, faz coisas como `1+1=5+2;` não teria sentido. O que exatamente esta tentando fazer?

Comment: Me parece uma mistura indevida de matemática com programação. A igualdade da matemática tem que ser convertida para atribuição, de forma à variável ficar na esquerda do `=` (em matemática o `=` é a igualdade. na maior parte das linguagens o `=` é atribuição, como respondido pelo @guilherme). Exemplo:  `x-7=12` tem que ser "convertido" para `x = 12 + 7`. outro exemplo: `7 - y = n * 12` tem que virar `n = ( 7 - y ) / 12`, se você já tem o `y` e quer obter o `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sinal de igual `=` é usado para setar valores em variáveis, quando você faz:

```
(ano-10)/76=n-1;
```

Você tenta setar o valor de `n-1` para o valor de `(ano-10)/76`, mas isto não tem sentido e causa a falha, o sinal de igual deve ser usado com variáveis, como por exemplo:

```
int foo = n-1;
int bar = (ano-10)/76;
```

Mas depende muito do que você deseja fazer, também existe o `==` que é o sinal de comparação, por exemplo:

```
if (foo == bar) {
     //Acontece algo
}
```